# How to remove the controller name from the url in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`<p><a href="/Home/index2"/></p>` if I click on this `href` tag,we will call the index page in which we will access the webapi using ajax request.

> 'localhost/api/PdfViewer'

`<p><a href="/Home/index2"/99></p>` if i click on this href tag this have same functionality as a href above. But there is a webapi path is different

on passing the id the controller name gets added before.

> 'localhost/home/api/PdfViewer'.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for removing the controllername before the API.

Comment: Need to show the code where you are generating the url, also where exactly is `PdfViewer` defined.

Comment: Are you using some custom routing?

Comment: Hi ALL,thanks for the update.I have accessed the Web API controller by using the '@Url.Action("~/")' + api/PdfViewer .

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you have to use  razor extension `@Url.Action("~/")`  or

`@Url.Action("<ControllerName>","<ActionName>", null)` .

```
For Ex: <p><a href="@Url.Action("~/")"/></p>
```